# Replace a variable with the name of the file in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting, find

I have a scenario where I need to substitute a variable (the same variable) in multiple files within a directory with that name of the files.

For instance, I have a list of files with identical content as such;

file1
file2
file3
file4

The contents of each of these files is;

```
Some Text
Another line of text
I need to replace this $variable
```

What I would like to do is replace all instances of the pattern $variable with the name of said file.

i.e. the contents of file1 will become

```
Some Text
Another line of text
I need to replace this file1
```

and the contents of file2 will become

```
Some Text
Another line of text
I need to replace this file2
```

I have been looking into sed and think it's probably the way to go but I've often been wrong about scripting and it certainly isn't a strong point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for loop:

```
while read -r f; do
   sed -i.bak "s~\$variable~$f~" "$f"
done < <(grep -l '\$variable' file*)
```

Change glob pattern `file*` to `*` if you want to do this for each file in the directory.

Comment: Pretty sweet! That's excellent thanks mate. Excuse my ignorance but how do I get this to actually update the files in question instead of just outputting to the screen? - Thanks so much for the speedy response!

Comment: I think `/` may give conflict. Better use another delimiter.

Comment: Yes, `/` in the filename is going to be problematic with this as are any other characters that are magic in the replacement portion of `s///`.

Comment: @user3919278: Check updated command, it will now make inline edit rather than writing on stdout. konsolebox: thanks mate, I have used `~` now as delimiter.

Comment: `g` needs to be added if OP has `$variable` multiple times in same line.

Comment: You should just state that it will fail if the file name contains `&` or `\<number>` or `~` or if the text `$variablerate` or similar that you do not want replaced appears inthe file.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for inplace editing and word anchors:

```
awk -i inplace '{gsub(/\<\$variable\>/,FILENAME); print}' file*
```

The above will fail for file names containing `&` or `\\<number>`. If that's a problem the solution is to use match() or index() with substr() instead of a gsub().